# run php script automatically

Tags: php

i have a php script that should be run automatically every day.
as the php script is run on a request,how can i do it?
is there any way else using cronjob task?

Comment: Why you hate cronjob for this requirement?

Comment: Can you explain why the cron job is not fit here?

Comment: Came down friends,i have no problem with using cronjob,i just want to know about the ways others use to do such job to improve my knowledge and getting new idea and finding better ways to do works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use crontab demon
2. Hire a worker and make him open script in a browser every 24 hours

The choice is yours :)

To use crontab, type `crontab -e` in console, the text file opens. Add a line at the end:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/httpdocs/daily_stats.php
```

Where:

`0 0 * * *` - run every day at 00:00

`/usr/bin/php` -path to your PHP (can be determined by `which php` command)

`/var/www/mysite/httpdocs/daily_stats.php` - path to your PHP script

if `which php` outputs nothing, install PHP cli by running:

```
sudo aptitude install php5-cli
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

use cron job option who start automatically and give result before 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

Use the cron job, this is the best solution. 
otherwise, you can run an infinite loop inside php and sleep 24 hours. 
horrible solution though.

Answer (score 1):

If cron isn't available in some sort of way you could use Google app engine's [cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) for this. Because cron is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If cron is not available you could execute a php script in CLI which will run all the time.

In the script you can make a infinite while loop.

In the while loop, check a file on disk or a db record (you can controll this file or db record from an external script, telling the looping script what to do (CLI execute another script at a given hour) and when to exit)

If you use a database,don't forget to initialize and close the db connection each time the loop runs.

I'd sleep the loop every 1 min or so.. you could use this instead of linux cron for many more things.